# ERROR TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'keyv'

Tags: typescript, npm, types, node-modules, tsconfig

We have a code base that is built every night. Last night, it failed to build (without me making changes that were related to NPM libraries).

I got the following error:

```
ERROR TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'keyv'.
The file is in the program because: Entry point for implicit type library 'keyv'.
```

I found that the keyv library is not in my packages json, but some other packages that are listed in package.json are using it. In the package-lock.json I found @types/keyv is used in several places.

Searching for the types library and looking at the change in the package-lock.json lead to this line, and this is its link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/keyv
"This is a stub types definition. keyv provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed."

The packages using 'keyv' tried to use the @types/keyv which is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

`npm install -D keyv` solved this for me too.

Answer (score 3):

The way I solved it was to add the keyv library to my package.json.

Answer (score 1):

npm install -D keyv solved this for me too.
but i don't know why!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by re-locking package versions:
`rm package-lock.json && rm -rf node_modules && npm i`

The reasons behind why it worked, I have no idea. Perhaps some old version of "keyv" was laying around in "package-lock.json"

Anyway, I think the solution is much better than installing a package that you are not explicitly using in your code base